# Clicking #ManualRefresh causes loss of formatting in list view web part

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view

SP OnPrem 2019

I have a list view web part on my form and I enabled "Show Manual Refresh Button".  ***When I click the button manually (or with code), the view updates as expected, but it causes a loss of formatting on the view.***

In particular, Setting Column Widths and Removing the default Sort options on all columns.

Anything done in css seems to remain in place, like custom fonts.

**It's the customizations done via script that get lost.**

How I'm clicking the Manual Refresh button:

```
document.getElementById('ManualRefresh').click();

or

$('#ManualRefresh').click();
```

(But it also occurs when I click it manually.)

These are the functions I use to add the formatting:

```
function DisableListViewSorting(){
    //Disable all sort options in ALL list view web parts on this form
    //called from doc.ready
    //hide sort arrows
    $(".ms-listviewtable th").each(function(){       
        $(this).attr("onmouseover","");
        $(this).attr("onmousedown","");
    });
    //hide <a> link on column label
    $.each( $("[id^=diidSort]") , function () {
        $(this).parent().html("<span>"+$(this).text()+"</span>");       
    });
};


function SetListViewWebPartColumnWidths(){
    //Set width of individual columns here

  //Comments web part
    //Created
    $("div.ms-vh-div[DisplayName='Created']").attr("style", "width: 120px");

    //Created By
    $("div.ms-vh-div[DisplayName='Created By']").attr("style", "width: 120px");

    //Title - used to display Open link
    $("div.ms-vh-div[DisplayName='']").attr("style", "width: 20px");

    //Comment
    $("div.ms-vh-div[DisplayName='Comment']").attr("style", "min-width: 600px");

};
```

After triggering the Manual Refresh I've tried calling these functions again. I can see they run and set the custom widths for about a 1/10 of a second, but then they revert back to the smaller size and the sorting is enabled.

So the Manual Refresh is making these changes invalid.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

***Solved it by moving the 2 formatting functions to the JSLink file.***

In the JSLink call the functions like this:

```
var overrideCtx = {};
overrideCtx.Templates = {};
overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
    'LinkTitleNoMenu':{'View': GetTitleSpecial},  //Title field with link
    'TimeDifference':{'View': GetActivityLogTimeDifference},
    'ID':{'View': AddActivityLogStopButton},
    };

//Call custom formatting functions
overrideCtx.OnPostRender = [DisableListViewSorting,SetListViewWebPartColumnWidths];

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
```

After the Manual Refresh these options now stay in place.  Works in Chrome and IE 11.